# Not able to invoke the data from server in a web view in iOS with 'ios:'.concat(data)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webview

I am creating an application which loads a web view of a page to get data from the web view and save the data to the local SQLite database in the iOS application. Current the issue faced is, though the web view alerts the data, I am not able to receive the data in *Web View Delegate*, ie: I have tried to print in the log in the Web View Delegate area and even it is not showing.

```
URL : http://35.161.118.210/list/12345.html
```

**Server Page Data**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    setInterval(function(){
        var data = "Notice 1:::Notice 2:::Notice 3:::Notice 4:::Notice 5:::Notice 6";
            if(data.length > 5){
            window.location  =  'ios:'.concat(data);
            $('#notice').text("Unread Notice");
            alert(data);
            }
        }, 5000);
</script>
```

**Webview Load**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-64)];
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:USER_CODE];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:htmlFile];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

**Web View Delegate**

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSString *strResponse = [[request URL] absoluteString];

    NSLog(@"Value retured : %@",strResponse);

    if ([strResponse hasPrefix:@"ios:"]) {

        NSString *newString = [strResponse substringFromIndex:[@"ios:" length]];
        newString = [newString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"Value retured : %@",newString);

        UIAlertView *uiAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:newString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
        [uiAlert show];

        NSArray *arrItems = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@":::"];
        for (NSString *strItems in arrItems) {

            [strItems stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
            NSMutableDictionary *mDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [mDic setObject:strItems forKey:@"item_name"];
            [mDic setObject:@"0" forKey:@"is_deleted"];
            [[DataBase connection] insertTableData:mDic AndTableName:@"school_feed"];
        }

        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

info.plist
[image]

Comment: Did you declare `NSAppTransportSecurity` and `CFBundleURLTypes` in your `info.plist`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below code in your Webview Load

`webView.delegate = self`

For example :

**Webview Load**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-64)];
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:USER_CODE];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:htmlFile];
    webView.delegate = self;
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

Comment: Please include a semicolon after "webView.delegate = self"

Comment: @JithinU.Ahmed : Happy to hear.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've forgotten to declare your application as an `ios` URL scheme handler. To do that, add following into an `info.plist`:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.myapp.ios</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>ios</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```